# function with infinite loop through array with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a function in jQuery with infinite loop that would show the content of an array. It works fine with alert - it shows announcement 1 - 2 - 1 - 2 and so on. But when I try to add some animation - it shows only the second announcement.

Can somebody help me?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var announcements = ["<p>announcement 1<\/p>","<p>announcement 2<\/p>"];
    function showArrayOfAnnouncements() {
        for (i = 0; i<announcements.length; i++) {
// works very well:
        alert (announcements[i]);
// doesn't work:
//          $("#french_announcements").html(announcements[i]).hide().slideDown(500).delay(2000).slideUp(500);
    }
    showArrayOfAnnouncements();
}
showArrayOfAnnouncements();

});
```

Comment: Very bad to use recursion in infinite loop

Comment: Looks like you have a global var declaration in your loop (common mistake).  Haven't ran your code but it looks like by the time delay() is finished the value of i is 2 or the end of array. I'm guessing for (let I = 0; ...etc) might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not waiting for the animation to end before continuing the recursion, add the recursion call to the callback at the end of the animation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var announcements = ["<p>announcement 1<\/p>","<p>announcement 2<\/p>"];
    function showArrayOfAnnouncements(i) {
        alert (announcements[i]);
        $("#french_announcements").html(announcements[i]).hide().slideDown(500).delay(2000).slideUp(500, () => showArrayOfAnnouncements((i+1) % announcments.length);
    }
    showArrayOfAnnouncements(0); 
});
```

Comment: I corrected the typos, but it doesn't work. Could you please test it?

Comment: Fixed. Try now.